# How many clients does the airport express support when bridging (ProxySTA)?

Tags: network, wifi, airport

The airport express is said to support [50 users](http://www.apple.com/airport-express/), yet in my case (when bridging WiFi to ethernet) it only serves up to 4 clients on the LAN port. A fifth client is not able to obtain an IP address nor ARP requests or anything else. It's completely ignored by the airport express.

So: How many ethernet clients does the airport express support concurrently when bridging?

Note: This applies to bridged mode (ProxySTA) only, where one bridges an existing WiFi (connected to the internet) into an ethernet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same results. Only 4 clients receive an IP from the the main AP. Seems to be an undocumented hard limit on the Express when in client / proxysta mode